# One page accessible from more than one URL

Tags: url, seo

I used screaming frog to scan a website and it shows that there are two pages www.abcd.com and www.abcd.com/home both pointing at the home page. However, the URL displayed is `www.abcd.com` and the link in the view source is

```
<a href="http://abcd.com/home" style="font-size: 14px!important; color:#fff; ">Home</a>
```

Now my question is how to overcome this situation? Can I replace the `http://abcd.com/home` to `http://abcd.com`?

Comment: So when entering `/home` (or clicking this link), you get redirected to `/`? If yes, which redirect is used, 301? -- Or can you end up on `/home`?

Comment: Clarification is required. Check your website for the presence of the index file: open a similar link with your domain www.abcd.com/index (perhaps in the end you need to install the extension .html). Let us know whether this link is opened or not.